# SQL: how to find all replies to a deleted comment?

Tags: sql, select, missing-data

My **comments** table has these columns:

```
`comment_id` - comment
`parent_comment_id`  - a reply to comment.
```

I need to select all `comment_id` that have a missing (not exists) `comment_id` specified in their `parent_comment_id` column.

Basically, I need to select all replies to a deleted comment.

**An example:**

Mark says: Hello, how are you?
Jonh replies: I am fine, thank you.

In our DB these comments will look like this:
`comment id`                        `parent_comment_id`                        `comment_text`
       374                                             0                                     Hello, how are you?
        375                                           374                                   I am fine, thank you.

Now imagine, that `comment_id 374` got deleted from our DB. That would leave `comment_id 375` pointing to non-existant `comment_id` in their `parent_comment_id 374`.

So my question is how can I select such comments that are replies to comments that no longer exist?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, a clear explanation of the logic you want, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: here, i draw us a database :) I hope this will make it super clear, what i am asking for

Comment: Your current code selects comments like `374` but we need the opposite to find comments like `375`

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

> I need to select all comment_id that have a missing (not exists) comment_id specified in their parent_comment_id column.

You can use `not exists`:

```
select c.*
from comments c
where not exists (select 1
                  from comments cp
                  where cp.comment_id = c.parent_comment_id
                 );
```

Comment: No, this is wrong. Your code just selects all `comment_id` with `parrent_column_id` = 0. I need `parent_column_id` that are not empty and have a comment_id that is not missing.

Comment: @En0w1na . . . No, this does what your question seems to ask for -- selecting all comments whose parent id is not valid.  Your question doesn't even mention `parent_column_id = 0`, so I don't know how that fits in.

Comment: My `parent_column_id` contains a `comment_id` to which it belongs. Sometimes that 'comment_id' does not exist anymore because it was deleted.